# XmlObject.Factory.newInstance() error after upgrading xmlbeans.jar to 5.x.x

Tags: java, xmlbeans

I need to upgrade Apache's xmlbeans.jar in my project from version 3.1.0 to 5.0.3 because it's a dependency of another jar. But doing so messes up some legacy webservice-related code which utilize XmlBeans as an XML processor, causing compiler errors.

The errors all look like this:

```
SomeDocument doc = SomeDocument.Factory.newInstance();
```

... where SomeDocument extends XmlObject.

With the jar's prvious version, the newInstance() method returned an instance of SomeDocument, no problem. However, the new version is trying to create an instance of the parent XmlObject.

How should I refactor this code? Can I cast the XmlObject instance to SomeDocument? Or should I use the XmlObjectFactory instead, as suggested by its javadoc. And if I should, how can I refactor the above code using that class instead?

Comment: Can you please share error stacktrace

Comment: Not really, as this is a compile-time error. The different return type of the newInstance method results in a type mismatch.

Comment: if newer version is creating instance of XMLObject, then easy, quick fix can be just casting. That would resolve your compilation error. Eventually in XmlObjectFactory, you might need to do casting as well if I refer `newValue` method of XmlObjectFactory.